# Mongo DB Atlas database: MongoDB.Driver.Legacy driver is missing

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

In my C# application I'm not able to access my MongoDB Atlas database.

After creating a database on Atlas, I generate the string to access it and add the following lines in my code:

```
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.5kp6i.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
var database = client.GetDatabase("DBTest");
```

The error is always the same. It seems that the MongoDB.Driver.Legacy driver is missing (username and password are obfuscated):

[image]

I suppose there is something wrong with the packages installed. I installed the last version of the Mongo Drivers through the Nuget packages manager:

[image]

But I tested also some of the previous version of the same packages without any results.
What am I doing wrong?

The targeted framework is the 4.8, could it be the cause? I wouldn't want to change that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you don't need `mongocsharpdriver` nuget

Comment: thank you, I removed it but the problems persists

Comment: I would vote it's something on your side, make clean up remove all mongo nugets and consume them again

Comment: Just tried to remove all the nuget packages (even those not related to Mongo) and reinstall just the Mongo ones again. After cleaning up the solution and rebuild nothing changed.

Comment: try cleaning nuget cache too. What's project type?

Comment: still no results after clearing the nuget cache. I tried also with the 4.7.2 framework but the problem persists. It's a class library project for a Revit plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot, I found out that a possible solution is to copy the Legacy.dll file into the Program Files folder of the software.

[image]

This solution is not feasible for me, so I decided to create customized endpoints on MongoDB Atlas in order to access the database with email and password.